# JSON data not kept in order

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I have returned json data that is arranged from most views to least views, but it is arranged completely wrong in the table view... here is what it looks like

screenshot of table

[image]

here is the array returned

```
 {
    author = edmiester777;
    description = "test post #3";
    id = 3;
    imageURL = "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nmbZ4yKmKyQ/Tz6t5kpwAuI/AAAAAAAAADA/CO0s0VhvPDM/w800-h800/potion.jpg";
    pubDate = "2013-07-01 12:49:01";
    title = "Post #3";
    views = 64774;
},
    {
    author = edmiester777;
    description = "@*$(DS(XC#*$&@(())));";
    id = 1;
    imageURL = "http://0.tqn.com/d/sbinformation/1/0/D/A/twitter_newbird_boxed_whiteonblue.png";
    pubDate = "2013-07-01 12:21:01";
    title = "First Post Ever!";
    views = 1035;
},
    {
    author = edmiester777;
    description = "this post is testing the UIImage loading capability of the custom table view";
    id = 2;
    imageURL = "http://greatergood.berkeley.edu/images/uploads/Thnx4-logo-small.png";
    pubDate = "2013-07-01 12:46:28";
    title = "Second Post Ever!";
    views = 645;
}
```

what could be going wrong when displaying the data?

code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
Regular_Cell *cell;
// Configure the cell...
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_RECENT)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"default"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"default"];
        }
        [cell.title_label setText:[self.recent_array_titles   objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [cell.views_label setText:[self.recent_array_views    objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [cell.author_label setText:[self.recent_array_authors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [cell setPoll_idFromString:[self.recent_array_poll_id objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        //options for image view
        cell.desc_image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        NSString *imageURL = [self.recent_array_poll_images objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
        [cell.desc_image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_RECENT)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"See More"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"See More"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell = nil;
    }
}
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    if(indexPath.row < NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_TOP)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"default"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"default"];
        }
        [cell.title_label setText:[self.recent_array_titles   objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [cell.views_label setText:[self.recent_array_views    objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [cell.author_label setText:[self.recent_array_authors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [cell setPoll_idFromString:[self.recent_array_poll_id objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        //options for image view
        cell.desc_image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        NSString *imageURL = [self.recent_array_poll_images objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
        [cell.desc_image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_TOP)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"See More"];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[Regular_Cell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"See More"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell = nil;
    }
}

return cell;
 }
```

this is how i get each individual array

```
 -(void)addRecentCells
 {
NSArray *recArray = [Global_Vars get_json_results_for_recent];
self.recent_array_titles      = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.recent_array_authors     = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.recent_array_views       = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.recent_array_poll_id     = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.recent_array_poll_images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSDictionary *poll in recArray)
{
    [self.recent_array_titles      addObject:poll[@"title"]];
    [self.recent_array_authors     addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",poll[@"author"]]];
    [self.recent_array_views       addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Views : %@",poll[@"views"]]];
    [self.recent_array_poll_id     addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",poll[@"id"]]];
    [self.recent_array_poll_images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",poll[@"imageURL"]]];
    NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_RECENT = self.recent_array_titles.count;
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
 }
 -(void)addTopViewedCells
 {
NSArray *topArray = [Global_Vars get_json_results_for_top_viewed];
self.top_views_array_titles      = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.top_views_array_authors     = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.top_views_array_views       = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.top_views_array_poll_id     = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.top_views_array_poll_images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i = 0; i < topArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *poll = [topArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.top_views_array_titles      addObject:poll[@"title"]];
    [self.top_views_array_authors     addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Author: %@",poll[@"author"]]];
    [self.top_views_array_views       addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Views : %@",poll[@"views"]]];
    [self.top_views_array_poll_id     addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",poll[@"id"]]];
    [self.top_views_array_poll_images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",poll[@"imageURL"]]];
    NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_ROWS_TOP = self.top_views_array_titles.count;
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: How do you populate the contents of the table view? We would need to see methods in your view controller such as `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Presumably you're mucking things up in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: added code for populating table

Comment: @EddieCallahan you can store your json response in `NSMutableOrderSet` which preserves the order of your data, while in array it may get changed.

Comment: NSArrays will never change their order.

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara the NSMutableOrderedSet doesnt change anything, i checked it with all the values, everything returns the same

Comment: Trace through your code (and add NSLogs) and figure out where the order is getting bungled.  It should only take a few minutes to narrow it down.

Comment: (I think most people would just use your recArray and topArray arrays directly, vs breaking them into individual arrays like that.  That extra step just adds more complexity, with no real benefit.

Comment: @HotLicks, going directly from the arrays solves this error, my problem was that i was just making it too hard, thank you... i wish i could rate your comment as the answer =(

Comment: Always remember to keep it simple.  *Especially* when it's inherently complicated, keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should dump the output of your NSArrays after you populate them. Make sure your data is ordered correctly.

This would also be a great place to start using something like RestKit: http://github.com/RestKit/RestKit